# Whole content out of view

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, cocoapods

I have a Shuffle package added to my project (https://cocoapods.org/pods/Shuffle-iOS), the package works fine, but the problem is that even though I set `card`s width and height to my `UIView`, cards are out of `UIView` anyways, I tried changing the frame of my cards and set width and height to `UIView`s, but they are still out of `UIView` any solutions?

my `UIView` is `mainView` in code below

```swift
func card1(index: swipeCardData) -> SwipeCard {
    let card = SwipeCard()
    card.swipeDirections = [.left, .right, .up]
    card.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    card.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    card.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    card.layer.shadowRadius = 6.0
    card.layer.masksToBounds =  false
    card.layer.borderWidth = 2
    
    let view_bg = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 16, y: 60, width: mainView.frame.size.width, height: mainView.frame.height)) // here is set cards width and frame to my UIView
    card.content = view_bg
    view_bg.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    view_bg.clipsToBounds = true
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) { [self] in
        
        let view_bg1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view_bg.frame.size.width, height: view_bg.frame.size.height))
        
        card.content?.addSubview(view_bg1)
        
        let img_card_type = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        img_card_type.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        img_card_type.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        img_card_type.isHidden = true
        view_bg1.addSubview(img_card_type)
        img_card_type.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: view_bg1.centerXAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
        img_card_type.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view_bg1.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        img_card_type.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```

pictures for better understanding :

[image]

as you can see on the screenshot above the card content is out of `mainView` which is in the background(gray box)

the end result below

[image]

Comment: In the second scenario, Georgia - this looks like you got your desired result or not as it seems like your card is within your main view. So were you able to achieve that or is that just an example of what you want your end result to be ?

Comment: what is `mainView` and it's frame ? Everything seems good, I think it's mainView's frame is the issue. Try a fixed size instead of mainView's size. If fixed size work for you then you know what to fix.

Comment: @ShawnFrank its on iphone 11 simulator, the first screenshot is iphone 8

Comment: @BlindNinja `mainView` is an `UIView` from storyboard, frame comes from there

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are not providing height for image view and telling to expand according to aspect ratio of image. set a max height for image view. to better UX centre imageview in both axis and a fixed either height or width and a maximum for other width or height.

```
img_card_type.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: view_bg1.centerXAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
img_card_type.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: view_bg1.centerYAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
img_card_type.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
img_card_type.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```

Comment: you code makes all content inside card disappear, the card is still out of `UIView`

Comment: sorry to hear that, in the code you only had img card, it's layout constraints which are making all content disappear. show us full layout, we will be able to help effectively. tho what you want to do can be achieve by the code I sent but it's ONLY for image card, not for/with other content.